# how to add percent sign to string

Tags: objective-c, string

Sorry I'm a bit new to objective c and I can't find out how to do something as simple as include a percent sign in a string. How is this accomplished in objective c?

Here's what I tried:

```
 NSString *string = @"%";
    brightnessLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[@"Brightness: %.0f" stringByAppendingString:string],slider.value];
```

but the percent doesn't show up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you enter a new question, SO shows you possibly related questions. Please check these before posting. The first one listed is an exact duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use "%%". So like this:

```
NSString *string = @"%%";
```

If you want a number with a percent after it:

```
brightnessLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Brightness: %.0f%%", slider.value];
```